# Why electron moving with acceleration around nucleus is not emitting EM-waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, atomic-physics

I know that physics (beginnig with Bohr) say that while an electron is in any orbit (whle not jumping from orbit to orbit) it is not radiating EM-waves. But an electron in any orbit (even maximum stable orbits) is "kind of" rotating => curved path => acceleration => emits EM-waves. OK, more deeply it is not orbiting like earth etc (but why it has orbital momentum then?), it is a "cloud of probability" and stuff - but this is as a wave, as a particle it is moving with acceleration.

So, is electron within atom is moving with acceleration (curved path)? If yes, why no EM-emission?

Answer (score 0):

All we know is that an electron in an atomic orbital is described by a wave function. If you calculate the EM field of the charge distribution described by that wave function you will find no radiation field: it predicts a stationary charge and current distribution. As momentum is constant, there is no force or acceleration until there is a transition to another atomic orbital.

This is all that QM has to say about it. The rest is interpretation.